# Unable to give permission to run certain commands via sudoers

Tags: permissions, sudo, systemd

I have a user `auser`. I want `auser` to be able to run `/bin/systemd start certain.service` without a password.
To do this, I created a group `special_user` and added `auser` to it. Then, I created a file `users_file` under `sudoers.d` directory.
In `users_file`, with sudo + vim, I pasted this:

```
%special_user ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start certain.service
%special_user ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl stop certain.service
```

As root things work fine, but, when I try it with `auser` I am asked with a password which eventually fails with an error - "Sorry, auser is not allowed to execute that command as root". (I run command with sudo)
Upon doing `sudo -l`, while logged in as `auser`, I get the following output:

```
(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start certain.service
(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart certain.service
```

Please guide me as to how to do it correctly.

Comment: Have you logged out and logged back in yet?  Adding a user to a group doesn't take effect until that user relogs to the system (logs out, logs back in)

Comment: Yes Sir, I have. I logged-out `auser' then logged it back again, multiple times.

Comment: @ThomasWard It shows that `auser` has been added to `special_user`.

Comment: @ThomasWard It's working now, maybe vps takes some time to reflect changes. Once you have seen this comment, I'll delete the question.